# The probability of going to work

Tags: probability

[image]
I think the required is :

$P(Taxi | Bus) = 0.4$ which is already given .

I think i missed understanding some thing ?!

Comment: What you missed is that Wednesday is not one day away from Monday.

Answer (score 1):

She has $4$ options, what she does on Tuesday and what she does on Wednesday:

(A) Taxi|Taxi = $0.4\times0.3=0.12$
(B) Taxi|Bus = $0.4\times0.7=0.28$
(C) Bus|Taxi = $0.6\times0.3=0.18$
(D) Bus|Bus = $0.6\times0.7=0.42$

You want options (A) and (C), which is $0.3$.